# Does anybody know how UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent works in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios4

They added UIDataDetectorTypeAddress and UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent to IOS 4.0

I'm assuming that UIDataDetectorTypeAddress creates links to the Map application.

What does UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent create links for?  Is it detecting an Event in the user's calendar, or is it just detecting dates, etc.   I can't find any documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it will detect dates clicking on which should open the iPhone native calendar for you to add an event for that date.

Note: UIDataDetectorTypes won't work if your textView is editable.

You have to either set your textView to non-editable in the attributes of the textView if you are using the IB. Just select the textView and go to Tools->Attributes Inspector. Once there, uncheck the editable checkbox.

If you are adding your textView through code, then before adding the

```
textView.datadetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeCalendarEvent
```

write this line of code

```
self.textView.editable = NO;
```

then you can specify the dataDetectorTypes

```
self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```

If you want to load some text in the textView then do this:

```
self.textView.text = @"www.Apple.com";
self.textView.editable = NO;
self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
```